# Move files from android to linux

Tags: android, linux, raspbian

I'm writing an app for android, in this app I want to send a file to a Raspberry Pi device. I did some research and I realized I need to use `scp` command to do this.

```
scp path/to/file user@ip.of.linux:/path/to/destination
//I dont know where to put this code
```

Now I want to now that how can I run this linux command in my Android app? Is there a library for this? How can I run the `scp` and move my file from android to linux.

I'm using unity for android development. My android and linux device(Raspberry Pi) are connected to same wi-fi. Also I'm using Raspbian for the Pi device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scp` is a linux program and it may be absent on your android device (and usually android devices don't have `scp` installed).

I suggest to use on of next ways:

1) setup web server on Raspberry and send files via http
2) setup ftp server on Raspberry and send files via ftp
3) setup smb share on Raspberry, mount smb share on android and send files via smb

Comment: Can `ssh` be a way for sending files too ?

Comment: `scp` is a `cp` over `ssh`) And usually there are no ssh client or server on android device out-of-the-box. Of course you may install ssh and scp to your device but it may require root or re-built ssh/scp utils.  Are you sure that you want to do it? Anyway you may run terminal command from your app as `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec({command});` and get input/output streams of process to read command output/write to command.